# compilation error in webkit-gtk

Tags: linux, webkit, gtk, directfb

I am getting following error while compiling webkit-gtk for directfb, any guess how to resolve it?

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sunny/svn/iSense-E/trunk/stable/thirdp/src/webkit-1.2.0/WebKitBuild/Release'
/bin/mkdir -p ./.deps/DerivedSources
  CC     WebKitTools/GtkBonker/Programs_GtkBonker-GtkBonker.o
  CXX    WebKitTools/DumpRenderTree/gtk/Programs_DumpRenderTree-LayoutTestControllerGtk.o
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:87:30: error: gdk/gdk-directfb.h: No such file or directory
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:257: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:287: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:795: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c: In function ‘sampleGTKApplicationInitialize’:
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:814: error: ‘gp_f_gdkDirectFbSetInitializationParameters’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:814: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:814: error: for each function it appears in.)
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:814: error: ‘sampleGTKApplicationDirectFbSetInitializationParameters’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:815: error: ‘gp_f_gdkDirectFBCreateWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:815: error: ‘al_gtkDirectFBCreateWindowHandler’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:816: error: ‘gp_f_gdkDirectFBDestroyWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:816: error: ‘al_gtkDirectFBDestroyWindowHandler’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c: In function ‘sampleGTKApplicationTerminate’:
../../WebKitTools/GtkBonker/GtkBonker.c:841: error: ‘gp_f_gdkDirectFbSetInitializationParameters’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[1]: *** [WebKitTools/GtkBonker/Programs_GtkBonker-GtkBonker.o] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

The include path given to your compiler doesn't have gdk/gdk-directfb.h.

Either it's not installed and you need to install DirectFB or the makefile needs to be told where to look for it by adding a -I/path/to/directory/containing/gdk/gdk-directfb.h to the CC command.